# Delphi Make and Resource Compiler

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to get the `Make` target work from the Delphi command-line compiler. If I change a code change, then the targets in a groupfile are rebuilt, as I would expect. If I then re-run the script, with no changes, then the targets are not recompiled, but the binaries are 'processed' by the resource compiler, meaning they always get rebuilt, even if there are no actual code changes at all.

I am using Delphi 10.2, but I assume this is the same in previous versions too.

Is this expected behaviour?